# Using CORR() function on query with table join

Tags: google-bigquery

I get a null value when using the CORR() function on a table join query. However, on a query without a join the CORR() function returns a value. I get values for the other fields. I have tried giving the fields aliases, or no aliases, but I cant seem to get a value for correlation in Query 2.

Thanks in advance.

---

**Query 1**
Returns a value for correlation.  Query and result json link below.

```
select DATE(Time ) as date, ROUND(AVG(Price),2) as price, ROUND(SUM(amount),2) as volume, CORR(price, amount) as correlation

from

ds_5.tb_4981, ds_5.tb_4978, ds_5.tb_4967

where YEAR(Time) = 2014

group by date

order by date ASC
```

Query 1 result json: https://json.datadives.com/64cbd7a4a5aba3a864b17a719148620f.json

---

**Query 2** 
Null value for correlation. Query and result json link below.

```
select bitcoin.date as date, bitcoin.btcprice, blockchain.trans_vol,  CORR(bitcoin.btcprice,blockchain.trans_vol) as correlation

from

(select DATE(time) as date, AVG(price) as btcprice
from

ds_5.tb_4981, ds_5.tb_4978, ds_5.tb_4967

where YEAR(Time) = 2014

group by date) as bitcoin

JOIN
(select
DATE(blocktime) as date, SUM(vout.value) as trans_vol
from ds_14.tb_7917, ds_14.tb_7918, ds_14.tb_7919, ds_14.tb_7920, ds_14.tb_7921, ds_14.tb_7922, ds_14.tb_7923, ds_14.tb_7924, ds_14.tb_7925, ds_14.tb_7926, ds_14.tb_7927, ds_14.tb_7928, ds_14.tb_7934, ds_14.tb_7972, ds_14.tb_8016, ds_14.tb_8086, ds_14.tb_9743, ds_14.tb_9888, ds_14.tb_10084, ds_14.tb_10136, ds_14.tb_10500, ds_14.tb_10601
where YEAR(blocktime) = 2014
group by Date) as blockchain

on bitcoin.date = blockchain.date

group each by date, bitcoin.btcprice, blockchain.trans_vol

order by date ASC
```

Query 2 result json: https://json.datadives.com/9427dc9f51ba36add5f008403def7b6d.json

Comment: Can you write the same queries over a public dataset or open yours? Is much easier for anyone trying to help if they can run the problematic queries.

Comment: Yea sorry Felipe. I was wondering if it was my syntax and/or a feature not supported. I shared the datasets with you if thats ok. In the future I will use public datasets in questions.

Comment: I'm still traveling. Can you make a sample public so someone else can answer the question?

Comment: Will do. Your a true jet-setter :)

Comment: One quick question: Are you certain that the join query returns rows? That is, if you remove the CORR and retry the outer query, does it return rows? Can you also verify that both of the fields you are correlating have nonnull values?

Comment: Jordan: Yes. It is returning rows for the other 2 values. I also tried to load the original result, without the correlation field, into a new table and just do a CORR on the two fields. Perhaps having null values (which I dont know if there are) are causing the error. Here is the original query result, without the CORR. If I load this into a new table and query the two fields with CORR(btc_price, trans_vol) I still get null for CORR result. [Link to CSV to create new table](http://storage.googleapis.com/datadivessharing/result.csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the CSV you linked and left it here: https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:public_dump.datadivescsv

(I'm not sure why would you prefer to share the csv by file, instead of creating a public dataset in BigQuery and sharing the link)

So this works:

```
SELECT CORR(btc_price, trans_vol)
FROM [fh-bigquery:public_dump.datadivescsv] 

-0.004957046970769512
```

But this doesn't:

```
SELECT CORR(btc_price, trans_vol)
FROM [fh-bigquery:public_dump.datadivescsv]
GROUP BY date

null
null
...
null
```

And that's expected!

Why: To compute a correlation we need sets of more than 2 numbers. Grouping by date on the second query leaves us with n-groups of 1 element, hence correlation is non computable.

(Side note: Correlation between 2 elements is always 1 or -1. We really need at least 3 elements, and way more for the results to be significant)

```
SELECT CORR(x, y)
FROM (SELECT 1 x, 2 y)
null

SELECT CORR(x, y)
FROM (SELECT 1 x, 2 y), (SELECT 3 x, 8 y)
1.0

SELECT CORR(x, y)
FROM (SELECT 1 x, 2 y), (SELECT 3 x, 8 y), (SELECT 7 x, 1 y)
-0.3170147297373293
```

... and so on

Comment: Aha. I see. Thanks for pointing this out! Sorry for not sharing it via BQ, I did not think of it. Would make sense just to share and allow others to see the example too. Once again, thanks Felipe :)